# Is there an attribute called rect.center in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I was looking through a pygame tutorial and encountered the following part of a script:

```
fontObj = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render('hellow world', True, Green, Blue)
textRectObj = textSurfaceObj.get_rect()
textRectObj.center = (200,150)
```

The last line set the center of the rect at (200.150)
I looked through the pygame documentation and there is no center attribute in the Rect class.
But the script works... why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs on rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

> The Rect object has several virtual attributes which can be used to move and align the Rect:
>
> x,y
>
> top, left, bottom, right
>
> topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
>
> midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
>
> **center**, centerx, centery
>
> size, width, height
>
> w,h

I've bolded `center`.